# Error: Unable to resolve image URL from source (undefined) | Next js typescript with sanity backend

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, sanity

I checked my source code and everything. looks okay! But problem comes only when working with Next Js  Image tag. So creating schemas with sanity, then building the client and url Builder, importing client and builder to the file...I don't know if the issues are coming from there or not but its a problem that nobody solved in the past which I faced it finally. Issue doesn't show in your code editor. Only shows in web browser

heres the codes and screenshots:

**Sanity Schema**
[Schema for the city image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7ko6.png)

```
export default {
  name: "cities",
  title: "Cities",
  type: "document",
  fields: [
    {
      name: "cityImage",
      title: "City Image",
      type: "image",
      options: { hotspot: true },
    },
    {
      name: "cityName",
      title: "City Name",
      type: "string",
    },
  ],
};
```

**Building client and url Builder**
[Client and ImageUrlBuilder to get url from the backend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HM4kc.png)

```
import sanityClient from "@sanity/client";
import imageUrlBuilder from "@sanity/image-url";

export const client = sanityClient({
  projectId: "xxxxxxx",
  dataset: "xxxxxxxx",
  apiVersion: "xxxxxxxxx",
  useCdn: true,
  token: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SANITY_TOKEN,
  ignoreBrowserTokenWarning: true,
});

const builder = imageUrlBuilder(client);

export const urlFor = (source) => builder.image(source);
```

**Main issue appears here:**
[No error in code editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sWSSf.png)

```
<div>
            <input
              onChange={(e) => setSearch(e.target.value)}
              className={Styles.searchInput}
              type="text"
              placeholder="Search your city..."
            />
            <ul className="grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-3 lg:grid-cols-4 gap-6 text-center">
              {cityData
                .filter((city) => {
                  return search === ""
                    ? city
                    : city.cityName.toLowerCase().includes(search);
                })
                .map((city, i) => (
                  <li key={i} className={Styles.cityList}>
                    <Image
                      src={urlFor(city.cityImage && city.cityImage).url()}
                      alt=""
                    />
                    {city.cityName}
                  </li>
                ))}
            </ul>
          </div>
```

**Final output in Browser**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PGsp7.png)

I tried every possible way to fix it, but no result, looks like its a bug from sanity or next js. Also I've checked my package.json file too. All good

**Heres my  package.json**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cb0Co.png)

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@lottiefiles/lottie-player": "^1.6.3",
    "@portabletext/react": "^2.0.1",
    "@sanity/client": "^3.4.1",
    "@sanity/image-url": "^1.0.2",
    "next": "latest",
    "next-sanity": "^4.1.2",
    "next-sanity-image": "^5.0.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-device-detect": "^2.2.2",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-hot-toast": "^2.4.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.6.0",
    "react-lottie-player": "^1.5.4",
    "swiper": "^9.0.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "18.11.3",
    "@types/react": "18.0.21",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.0.6",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.13",
    "postcss": "^8.4.21",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.2.4",
    "typescript": "4.8.4"
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome, try to share text, log, errors and so on as text not as image. The same is valid for json structs

Comment: Do all items in the `cityData` array have a `cityImage` or there is a possibility that this could be `undefined` for one of those?

Comment: @KargWare Everything is there... text and image both for your better understanding the case

Comment: @ivanatias Thanks!!! actually in my backend, 2 items didn't have any image.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @ivanatias !

There was a problem with my backend, I had to attach image to all my items. If you do not have image attached to one of your item will cause the issue, then simply use dummy image or use this code will solve your problem if you don't wanna add image to your item at the moment -

```
{data.image && (<Image src={urlFor(data.image).url()})}
```